# PHP mail form - not posting a variable

Tags: html, forms, html-email, php

Everything but 1 (one) variable seems to be working on my mail form. On my HTML page I have a form with a select box, some text inputs and a textarea for the message. Everything besides the message variable is being retrieved.

I've never been all that good with these PHP-based mail forms. I usually use HTML mailto forms, but they're unsafe and pretty elementary.

I'd appreciate your help. Thanks!

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="php/contact.php">
            <label for="senderName">name:</label> <input name="senderName" type="text" /><br />
            <label for="senderEmail">email:</label> <input name="senderEmail" type="text" /><br />
            <label for="senderRegarding">subject:</label> 
                <select name="senderRegarding">
                    <option value="start a project">Wish to start a project</option>
                    <option value="request resume password">Request resum&eacute; password</option>
                    <option value="other">Other</option>
                </select><br />
            <label for="senderMessage">message:</label> <textarea name="senderMessage"></textarea><br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" /> <input type="reset" />
        </form>
```

**PHP**

```
    <?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
     $name = $_POST['senderName'];
     $email = $_POST['senderEmail'];
     $regarding = $_POST['senderRegarding'];
     $message = $_POST['message'];

     $subject = "Contact Form";

     $message = 
     "Name: " . $name . "\r\n" . 
     "Email: " . $email . "\r\n" . 
     "Subject: ". $regarding . "\r\n" .
     "Message: " . $senderMessage;

     $headers = 
     "From: " . $name .  "\r\n" .
     "Reply-To: " . $email . "\r\n" .
     "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
     "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\n";

     $to = "email@address";
};
     mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
     header("Location:../index.htm");
?>
```

Comment: its "senderMessage" not "message"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at your code the textarea is called "senderMessage" and your $_POST is looking for "message".

Change $_POST['message'] to $_POST['senderMessage'] and it will work

**Existing**

```
$message = $_POST['message'];
```

**Change To**

```
$message = $_POST['senderMessage'];
```

Comment: Haha! Wow. Color me embarrassed. Thanks a bunch. Sometimes it takes a new pair of eyes to see the simplest things.

Comment: Yeah definitely!!! No problem.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly recommend not using PHP's built-in `mail()` function; it's really awful. You end up with horrible looking code; you have to manually construct all the headers; and it's wide open to bugs.

Instead, download a copy of [phpMailer](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/).

This is a class which makes sending emails in PHP a piece of cake.

```
require("class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->From     = $from;
$mail->AddAddress($to);
$mail->Subject  = $subject;
$mail->Body     = $body;
$mail->Send();
```

Much simpler, I'm sure you'll agree. And also more secure, easier to work with, and more functional.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that replacing

```
 $message = $_POST['message'];
```

for

```
 $message = $_POST['senderMessage'];
```

will likely solve your problem. Alternatively you can change your `<textarea name="senderMessage></textarea>` to `<textarea name="message"></textarea>`

Comment: It an answer is correct, please mark as so, otherwise stackoverflow won't ever know that your problem has been solved. Consider up vote questions that somewhat made a contribution to your problem, doing so you may help others with similar questions to find the answers more easily

Answer (score 2):

It should be `$message = $_POST['senderMessage'];`